# Populating hashmap from a hashset from an other class

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have a hashset in a class called myClass that contains 6 strings.

I want to be able to create a hashmap and use these 6 strings as keys in another class called Maps, and they values beside.

how can i call the hashmap from the map class and use the 6 Strings from the hashset in myClass.

Comment: The only question should be what the values should be, using the set and map is one of the most trivial things to do in Java. Its not clear to me why you believe you need a Map.

Comment: its an assignment. i can easily create both individually but i am missing the point where i use a set from one class in a map from another. I cant seem to find a definate way so far. I can add a set into a map from the same class alright though..

Comment: @user1761732 Could you provide some code as to what have you tried yet? What's the issue in iterating over the set and putting those values as keys in your new map against some values.

Comment: the 6 strings are just random classed from the java api lib and the values for the map should be their packages.

Comment: public class MyFavouriteClasses
{
  Set<String> classes;
  
public MyFavouriteClasses()
    {
        
    }
    
   public void populate()
    
    {
    //HashSet<String> classes = new HashSet<String>();
    classes = new HashSet<String>();
    
    classes.add("ArrayList");
    classes.add("Hashset");
    classes.add("Random");
    classes.add("AbstractList");

Comment: the second is just a basic hash map but im not sure the easiest way to get the set implemented. i was trying //HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> mappings = new HashMap<String>>, HashSet<String>>();

Comment: please write your code in your question itself for better reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyFavouriteClasses { 
    Set<String> classes; 
    public MyFavouriteClasses() { } 
    public Set populate() { 
        Set<String> classes = new HashSet<String>(); 
        classes = new HashSet<String>(); 
        classes.add("ArrayList"); 
        classes.add("Hashset"); 
        classes.add("Random"); 
        classes.add("AbstractList"); 
        return classes;
    }
}

public class MyFavoriteMapClass {
    Map<String, String> map; 
    public MyFavoriteMapClass() { } 
    public void populate() { 
        MyFavouriteClasses class = new MyFavouriteClasses();
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Set<String> classes = class.populate(); 
        for(String str:classes) {
          map.put(String, (Class)str.getPackage());
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: ah i see..i'll work with that.. thanks.... i havent used the part with str. before. but this will help alot